# How to change the word size of "list of table"?

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

I use below code,

```
\listofrequirement

\listoftables
```

but the output is like this, the size of  "list of tables" is too big, how to make it smaller like the size of "list of requirements"?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This is necessary for multiple reasons. One of them is that we do not know where `\listofrequirement` comes from.

Comment: Same user, same appearance, same solution. But i voted the other to close. Feel free to vote to close here as well.